# The electron: why can't it have both momentum and position

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem

Total amateur here. I've been watching video lectures on Quantum Mechanics and it's said that there is no way to know both position and momentum of an electron at the same time. But is it because when people measure one they change the other or because the particle somehow can't have both inherently. If it is the latter, is there any non-mathematical way to explain how come?

Comment: The Heisenberg uncertainty principle dictates to what extent, simultaneously, we may measure momentum and position with respective uncertainties. What part are you unclear about?

Comment: To rephrase a little it's not clear whether the measurement tools are not perfect or electron somehow doesn't have both momentum and position and only one or the other (which seems weird)

Comment: @ACuriousMind yes, I should have searched better

Comment: Are you familiar with commutators?